# Ask for key password when OpenPGP signing mail in Thunderbird 78

Tags: passwords, thunderbird, openpgp

Thunderbird 78 has native OpenPGP functionality and I have imported my keys (after using Enigmail for many years). Upon doing so, it asked me for the key passwords and I presume it stores these somewhere secure. (I couldn't find it in the usual place.)

When sending mail, by default e-mails are signed with my key. However, it never asks me for the key password. Is there a setting that forces Thunderbird to always require the key password when signing mail?